# Airflow statsd exporter does not respond

Tags: docker, curl

I have airflow instance running on my server.
There is statsd-exporter running in docker.
However `curl localhost:<binded_port>/metrics` returns `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.
And `curl <host_ip>:<binded_port>/metrics` returns `curl: (28) Failed to connect to <ip> port <port> after 7137 ms: Connection timed out`.
Just yesterday it worked fine.

`docker logs <statsd_container>` returns fine logs with `accepting prometheus requests addr=:9102`. Docker run command contains `-p <binded_port>:9102`. On other server after using this command metrics are available on `curl localhost:<binded_port>/metrics`